# Setting up kaleido for plotly in rust

Tags: rust, plotly

I was going through this [plotly.rs](https://igiagkiozis.github.io/plotly/content/getting_started.html) tutorial on getting started with using plotly in rust and was trying to get the `kaleido` feature working. However, it seems to be breaking. Even the simple statement

```
plot.save("scatter", ImageFormat::PNG,  1024, 680, 1.0);
```

fails with the following rust backtrace (I'm on a Macbook).

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotPresent', /Users/devil/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/plotly_kaleido-0.2.0/src/lib.rs:88:66
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/f1edd0429582dd29cccacaf50fd134b05593bd9c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:517:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/f1edd0429582dd29cccacaf50fd134b05593bd9c/library/core/src/panicking.rs:100:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/f1edd0429582dd29cccacaf50fd134b05593bd9c/library/core/src/result.rs:1616:5
   3: plotly_kaleido::Kaleido::new
   4: plotly::plot::Plot::save
   5: test_plotly::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

The [plotly.rs repo](https://github.com/igiagkiozis/plotly) says that the `kaleido` needs further configuration, but I dont seem to find what I need to fix to get it working.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the latest version of `plotly_kaleido`? For me this works fine on macos.

Comment: Ah! Updating to plotly 0.7.0 fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [location where the error occurs](https://github.com/igiagkiozis/plotly/blob/b18758efc210fa3963ad8f009e9c96ec474f6385/plotly_kaleido/src/lib.rs#L88) it seems as if the `cargo` environment variable [CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts) is not set on your system.

This may happen if you ran your application directly using `rustc` instead of `cargo run`.

Comment: I seem to get the same error even when running using `cargo run`